# WPF application message box

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a WPF application(A) deployed on to a Windows app server and hosted in IIS. 
I programmatically access this application from another WPF thick client application(B).

When the app A is launched from B,following message box(titled "Launching Application") comes up:

> **Verifying application requirements...this may take a few moments...**

Is there any way at all to get rid of this message box completely please?

Thanks.

Comment: It should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8577579/1018966

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up the "Verifying Application Requirements" window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565182/how-to-speed-up-the-verifying-application-requirements-window)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio -> Project -> Properties -> Publish -> Updates and either uncheck "The application should check for updates" or select "After the application starts".

The message box is only shown when the application is checking for updates before the application starts.

Comment: Thanks RMadd. tried the same,but no luck.I still do that message.Not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Maybe try enabling [enhanced logging](https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/enhanced-logging-in-clickonce-deployment) and see if that gives you more information about what's going on.